# Postfix is appending myorigin to non-FQDNs despite "append_at_myorigin = no"

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server, fqdn

I have postfix and a local LMTP server running. In my main.cf, I have `append_at_myorigin = no`. When I run `postconf|grep append_at_myorigin` I get that this value is no.

But for some reason, postfix is still appending myorigin to non-FQDNs (i.e. sending to user becomes user@my-devices-hostname), and unsurprisingly the LMTP server has no idea what to do with these rewritten addresses.

Why is postfix doing this, and how can I make it stop?

Answer (score 0):

According to: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html, append_at_myorigin should not be changed.
Without seeing your logfiles, it's a bit hard to understand what's going on. Try setting verbose logging for the snmpd in master.conf " snmpd -v

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

**the man page**

```
append_at_myorigin (default: yes)
With locally submitted mail, append the string "@$myorigin" to mail addresses without domain information. With remotely submitted mail, append the string "@$remote_header_rewrite_domain" instead.

Note 1: this feature is enabled by default and must not be turned off. Postfix does not support domain-less addresses.

Note 2: with Postfix version 2.2, message header address rewriting happens only when one of the following conditions is true:

The message is received with the Postfix sendmail(1) command,
The message is received from a network client that matches $local_header_rewrite_clients,
The message is received from the network, and the remote_header_rewrite_domain parameter specifies a non-empty value.
To get the behavior before Postfix version 2.2, specify "local_header_rewrite_clients = static:all".
```